# Prove a Hilbert-like matrix is invertible

Tags: calculus, matrix-calculus, hilbert-matrices

Given an $m \times m$ matrix $M$ with $i,j$-th entry
$$
M_{i, j} = \frac{\frac{1}{i+1}+\frac{1}{j+1}}{i+j}, \quad i,j=1,\ldots,m
$$

This is a Hilbert-like matrix. I have numerically checked that it is invertible but I don't know how to prove it.

I was thinking that $\frac{\frac{1}{i+1}+\frac{1}{j+1}}{i+j} = \frac{1}{(1+i)(1+j)} + \frac{2}{(1+i)(1+j)(i+j)}$, so to prove that $M$ is invertible, it suffices to show that another matrix $N$ with entry $[N]_{i,j} = \frac{1}{(1+i)(1+j)(i+j)}$ is invertible.

Comment: Are you sure the inverse has integer entries when you do it numerically? For $m = 3$ I get $M = \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 5/18 & 3/16 \\ 5/18 & 1/6 & 7/60 \\ 3/16 & 7/60 & 1/12 \end{pmatrix}$ and $M^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 864/7 & -3960/7 & 3600/7 \\ -3960/7 & 20250/7 & -19440/7 \\ 3600/7 & -19440/7 & 19200/7 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Sorry for a mistake, have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $N$ is invertible as the product of invertible matrices $DHD,$ where $M$ is the Hilbert matrix and $D$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $(1+i)^{-1}.$

The sum is invertible as $DMD$ and the one dimensional matrix with entries $(1+i)^{-1}(1+j)^{-1}$ are positive definite and $DMD$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I got it